# I am altering shipping items knockout template where I came across ko-checked binding. What is the difference between ko-checked and checked binding?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, checkout-page

Ko-checked is a binding used in magento checkout in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html` file. If anyone knows more about this binding? How it is different from checked binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a differences between them when comes to radio button
ko-checked checks the radio button for the first time and it somehow persists the value even if the template is re rendered.

If checked binding is used here whenever address is changed the user selection will be reset because of re rendering of the shipping methods block.
Please share if you know more on this binding!.